# CallLog - field type

Tags: android, telephony

I've written a test app to read the call log.
There are 3 types of field -> **`incoming, outgoing, missed`**

In the emulator, I get the type `missed` after not picking up the phone.
If I reject the call, I will get the type `incoming`.

On my HTC Hero phone I get always the type `missed`.
On not picking up and if I reject the type field is always `missed` type.

Is this a bug in the HTC Hero?

Comment: What does it show in your phone's actual call log app?  Is this specifically a Sprint Hero device?  Not the European Hero?  I've seen tons of bugs of this magnitude with Sprint Heros so it wouldn't surprise me if you just found another.  Also, I just tested rejecting a call on my Nexus One and it shows as incoming, not missed.

Comment: Thanks for the test with Nexus One.
The HTC Hero (European) shows instead of incoming a missed call.
Is there any user out there with another HTC phone?
So i can see if its a HTC Hero problem or a problem with all HTC phones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because HTC don't differentiate between "rejected" and "missed"!
For the HTC phones "rejected" and "missed" its the same.

I don't know why, but the support center of HTC has told me that this is a great feature of HTC phones !?!? Very strange :-)